# Where can I see your tweets?

Tags: twitter

Refer a service where you can see your tweets. I am looking for services like these two: http://allmytweets.net, http://greptweet.com/u/twitter/
I want to find something similar, preferably in Open-Source.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You don't really provide many parameters of use for us here (languages? You cite other services, and say you want a service, but also say you want an open-source solution. I'll attempt an answer nonetheless...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware (off the top of my head) of available open-source solutions for the base task you're requesting and I'm not inclined to just go Googling around for one, but it isn't particularly difficult to replicate on your own, given you aren't afraid to write some code.

The first step is to visit https://dev.twitter.com/ and get started with registering your own application and getting your consumer key and secret. You'll also want to use Twitter's list of code libraries to find an available Twitter oauth library in a language you can use for your project. A good bet is PHP; Abraham's TwitterOauth library has served me well, myself.

Assuming the account's tweets aren't private, you can use your own application and user access keys to request batches of tweets. After a successful request to the API method [`GET statuses/user_timeline`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) wherein you specify a `since_id` of `0`, you'll make a new request in which you specify that the `since_id` is the same as the greatest ID from the last batch; you can continue this until the number of results you get back is 0 (you can't simply assume you're done when you get less than your specified `count` results back, as some circumstances can result in omitted tweets from your result set.)